# confusion around the definition of almost surely

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Z$ be a continuous random variable that is almost surely strictly positive and $A$ a set.

How can we write the fact that the random variable $1_AZ$ is $P-$almost surely zero ? with $P$ a probability measure.

My attempt :

$P[1_A Z = 0] = 1 \Rightarrow P[1_A = 0 or Z = 0] = 1 \Rightarrow P[1_A = 0] = 1 $ cause $Z$ is almost surely strictly positive.

Is this is right? But again we're dealing with continuous random variables, how can I write the integrals?  Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Regarding your question of how to write things using integrals, there is missing information and so this becomes a hard question to answer. What's missing are: the space --- perhaps an interval --- which serves as the sample space, and hence is the domain of the continuous random variable $Z$; and the probability distribution function on that interval.

Answer (score 2):

First, although your second implication is correct, your justification of it is incomplete. But you can justify it (without integrals) by applying the inclusion/exclusion formula: 
\begin{align*}
P\bigl[(1_A=0) \,\,\text{or}\,\, (Z=0)\bigr] &= P[1_A=0] + P[Z=0] - P\bigl[(1_A = 0) \,\,\text{and}\,\, (Z=0)\bigr] \\ &= P[1_A=0]
\end{align*}
where the last equation follows because middle term $P[Z=0]$ is zero, and the last term is also zero because 
$$P\bigl[(1_A = 0) \,\,\text{and}\,\, (Z=0)\bigr] \le P[Z=0]
$$
Next, when you say "How can we write the fact...", it sounds to me that you are asking whether the statement $P[1_A=0]=1$ is *logically equivalent* to the given statement $P[1_AZ=0]=1$. So, your argument is not complete unless you can also prove the converse direction, namely 
$$P[1_A=0]=0 \implies P[1_AZ=0]=1
$$

Comment: thanks that is clear. what about writing this in form of integrals? I really need that and i'm quite stuck with it.

Comment: For instance, I'm not sure how to write $P[1_A Z = 0 ] = 1$ (or simply the definition of the almost surely concept in this case) for continuous random variables and with integrals